# Undefined index: ingresarsim in C:\xampp\htdocs\TRABAJO\index.php\variable.php on line 7

Tags: php, html

Me aparece ese error en la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
$ingresarSim = $_POST['ingresarsim'];
```

ingresarsim lo tengo en el siguiente form:

```
<form method="post">
    <h1>INGRESAR LOS DATOS</h1>
    Ingresar SN/SIM
    <input type="text" name="ingresarsim">
    <br>
    <br>
   Numero movil
    <input type="text" name="numero">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="start">Seleccion fecha de entrega:</label>

    <input type="date" id="start" name="tripstart"
     value="2020-10-13"
     min="2000-1-1" max="2100-12-31">
    <input type="submit" name="activarsim" value="Activar sim">


</form>
```

Aqui es donde inclui el archivo en donde pienso declarar la variable de ingresarsim:

```
<?php

include ("registrarventas.php");
include ("variable.php");

?>
```

Comment: En qué archivo está el form y la data de este a qué archivo viaja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te está diciendo el problema. En el POST que estás procesando, no está definido ese campo. Podrías verificar si el valor está definido antes de usarlo:

```
if (isset($_POST["algunindice"]) {
    $valor=$_POST["algunindice"];
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya se soluciono

Answer (score 0):

Debes considerar los siguientes aspectos:

- A tu `form` le hace falta el atributo `action` para indicar a que archivo viajará la data
- Lo anterior por que cuando tu solicitas con `$_POST['algo'];` en el archivo destino PHP no encuentra de donde viene ese valor y te lo dará como NO definido.

Entonces en el formulario debes agregar esto:

```
<form action="ruta.php" method="POST">
```

Donde `ruta.php` es el archivo donde planeas usar la data que vieja de este formulario para asignarlo a tus variables

**Referencia**

- [atributo `action`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#configuring-a-form-to-communicate-with-a-server)

Comment: O sea que si la variable la estoy declarando en un archivo llamado: variable.php, debo poner action="variable.php"?

Comment: Ummm creo que no me expliqué bien @NathanaelDeLeon, si el formulario esta en `a.php` y la data planeas mandarla a `b.php` entonces en el action debes poner esto: `action=b.php` por que ahi es donde esperas llegue la información para hacer algo con ella

Comment: O sea no en donde declaro la variable, sino donde la usare, si la variable en cuestión la usare en 'b.php', pues tengo que poner: 'action=b.php'

Comment: la variable con la cul igualarás el valor recibido por POST debe estar declarada en el archivo destino, para este ejemplo sería en b.php

Comment: En el form ya puse el action indicando que la data viajara a ese archivo, y declare la variable en el archivo que la usare que es el mismo que puse en el action y aun asi no funciona

Comment: Ummm ya te debería funcionar, a ver has esto y dime que obtienes: `echo $_POST['ingresarsim'] ?? 0;`

Comment: Ya la reconoce la variable, gracias.

Comment: Que genial que bueno ya anda el código @NathanaelDeLeon chécate el enlace que puse en la respuesta la teoría fortalece mucho

Comment: Eso estoy hare cuando termine porque ahora me aparece otro error con otra cosa.